# Creating Random Corresponding Arrays in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, passwords

I made a question earlier on the same project but now I have a different problem. My goal is to have a password field that is stored locally and when a password is put in that is equal to the variable a screen will display. I have accomplished this but know I want to spice it up a little. I want to make it so that when the background color is red the password is red and so on for yellow and blue. I need to create two arrays that both randomly pick the same variable. I know this is possible because I have done it within Phaser but I am struggling on doing it in Android Studio. Anyways here is my code so far and my attempt at making an array.
Thanks for all the help,
Murdoc

```
package com.example.murdocbgould.passwordpt4;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.murdocbgould.passwordpt4.R;
import com.example.murdocbgould.passwordpt4.Welcome;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String apassword[] = {"rootr", "rootb", "rooty"};

        final String acolors[] = {"red", "blue", "yellow"};

        Random rn = new Random();
        int answer = rn.nextInt(3) + 1;



        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                textView2.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
                if(editText.getText().toString().trim().equals(apassword)){
                    Intent myIntentR1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(myIntentR1);
                } else {
                    Intent a = new Intent(view.getContext(), FTry.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn;t get you what you want?

Comment: You did but now I want to expand the project further for a college project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a bunch of if statements or use a switch statement. If you are going to write a serious app you would not store passwords in an array! I understand your in High School but consider using sqlite database it will open up a new world to develop apps. Storage of data is a wonderful learning experience. Back to your question here is a small snippet of IF code. In your case grab the password from the array and hard code the color to look for a match.
A better solution would be a HashMap key-value search the Map with the random password as the key and this will give a value that is a color. If you want both password and color to be random then use the IF statement concept

```
                if(!etPW.getText().toString().equals(etCPW.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Password Does NOT\n"+"Match Confirm Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etPW.setText("");
                etCPW.setText("");
                etPW.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: This didn't directly answer my question. It might of but it is a little more complicated. I am documenting what I am going to do here though so that anyone else reading this can receive help. I'm going to write an if statement saying that when the background color is red passwordA = redpassword and so on for each color. Now all I need to do is find a way to change the background color randomly and have it in a way were the program can recognize the color and set the variable accordingly.

Comment: @MurdocGould Well create a HashMap key = 1 Value = Color then limit Random generator to integers in the HashMap